# graph a piecewise function in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def f(x):

    if x<1/2:
        return x
    else x>=1/2:
        return 1-x
x=np.linspace(0,1,10)

y= f(x)
```

## I am trying to graph the function in python2.7

Answer (score 1):

answer 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    if x <= 0.5:
        return x
    else:
        return 1-x
x=np.linspace(0,1,10)

f2 = np.vectorize(f)
y = f2(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

answer 2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
y = x.copy()
y[y >= 0.5] = 1 - y[y >= 0.5]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```